# Distances are different by ~100-200m

Tags: geometry, geodesy

I'm measuring distance of 2 points on Google Map and then in my program converting them into ECEF using [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system#From_geodetic_to_ECEF). Then using Pythagorean theorem to calculate distance between those 2 points. Difference is about 100-200m, which is fairly big for what I am doing. In my program I use `double` for precision.

Big question will be what method Google is using in order to calculate distance between 2 points?

Update, example:

**Lon/Lat** : `44.50310895983847,40.16009701404741` and `44.50151117520584,40.15672510042466`. Google Earth says it's `400m`.

After converting to ECEF I get `3482269.0815067333, 2938590.6893090927` and `3482536.9833229352, 2938466.2491839984`. I measure distance of `276.99011m`

Comment: Please give an example of the points, your distance, and Google's distance.

Comment: ECEF is cartesian. Are you neglecting the curvature of the earth?

Comment: Yes I know it is Cartesian. I am calculating using the formula in my original post, which I believe considering that earth is elliptical.

Comment: This site may help you: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: It looks to me you have the longitude and latitude backwards.  Your longitude is very close to 45 deg, so the X and Y should be very close. I get (3486234, 3426284) and (3486501,3426356) but still get 277 m distance.

Comment: With $\Delta \phi = 0.003372$ I get the North-South distance as $6378137*0.003372*\frac \pi{180}\approx 375 m$ and $\Delta \lambda=0.0016$ gives EW as $6378137*0.0016*\cos (40.1584^\circ)\frac \pi{180}\approx 136 m$using a sphere, which supports the Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spherical Law of Cosines says
$$
\begin{align}
\cos\left(\frac{90^\circ}{10000\text{ km}}\text{dist}\right)
&=\sin(\text{lat}_1)\sin(\text{lat}_2)+\cos(\text{lat}_1)\cos(\text{lat}_2)\cos(\Delta\text{lon})\\
&=\cos(\Delta\text{lat})-\cos(\text{lat}_1)\cos(\text{lat}_2)(1-\cos(\Delta\text{lon}))\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Using the approximation $\cos(x)=1-\frac12x^2$ when $x$ is small yields
$$
\left(\frac{90^\circ}{10000\text{ km}}\text{dist}\right)^2
\stackrel.=\Delta\text{lat}^2+\cos^2(\text{lat})\Delta\text{lon}^2\tag{2}
$$
for small values of $\Delta\text{lat}$ and $\Delta\text{lon}$.

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta\text{lat}&=0.0033719136227^\circ\\
\Delta\text{lon}&=0.0015977846327^\circ\\
\cos(\text{lat})\Delta\text{lon}&=0.0012211298208^\circ
\end{align}
$$
With these values, I get $\text{dist}\stackrel.=398\text{ m}$.